# Declarative Environment Records and Scopes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

I am currently learning Javascript scopes, and try to put some rules for what is going on.
But every time unexpected behaviors broke them. So I need help please.

Consider the following Example

```js
console.log("v" in this);    //true
console.log(v)     //undefined
{
    {
        function a() {
            1;
        }
    }
    {
        function a() {
            2;
        }
        {
            function v() {
                3;
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log(a);    //ƒ a() {2}
```

function **v** is in memory but I can't use it at line 2. But in this example I can.

```js
console.log(v);
{
    function v() {
        1;
    }
}
```

I am confused about the rules that the compiler did before executing the script and what are the steps(Order) of evaluating declarations including statements use **let,const,var** and also **function** declarations and **class** declarations.
I have read blogs, books about scopes but nearly all of them treat variables, functions and classes as a stand alone stuff not a property attached in the D.E.R of the scope

Comment: Declarative Environment Record of the scope

Comment: *"function v is in memory but I can't use it at line 2. But in this example I can."* No, it's `undefined` as of where you log it, just like your first example.

Comment: Yes that's what I expect. but why the expression *"v" in this* evaluates to true. it means then it was in the memory (declared)

Comment: It means the *binding* (loosely, variable) has been created, not that the function has been created. The binding is initialized with the value `undefined`, and then it gets the function assigned to it later. I've explained how it works in my answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> function `v` is in memory but I can't use it at line 2. But in this example I can

No, both examples behave the same way. In both cases, `v` is declared inside a block, and in both cases, it had the value `undefined` as of where you log it.

In loose mode (aka "sloppy" mode), a function declaration in a block that fits certain criteria creates a hoisted binding (`v`, in this case) in the function (or global) scope, not block scope. That binding is initialized with the value `undefined`; it doesn't get the function assigned to it until the declaration is reached in the step-by-step execution of the code. There's *also* a block-local binding that shadows the function/global binding, which is initialized at the beginning of the block with the function. Yes, this is **very** confusing; it's because this was retroactively applying rules in ES2015 to the subset of common functionality across browser engines that had extended JavaScript with block-declared functions (which weren't in the spec, but were an allowable extension).

**But**, don't rely on that, or even really bother to commit it to memory. It's legacy compatibility stuff.

**Instead**, use strict mode, in which the declaration becomes local to the block (fully hoisted within the block) and you can't use `v` at all outside it:

```js
"use strict";
console.log("v" in this);    // false
console.log(v)               // ReferenceError
{
    {
        function a() {
            1;
        }
    }
    {
        function a() {
            2;
        }
        {
            function v() {
                3;
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log(a);
```

Comment: I understand what you want to say. thanks.
can you recommend me materials talk about this stuff in details.

Comment: At the risk of seeming^H^H^H^H^H^H^H *being* self-serving, there's [my book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119367956). **;-)** Out soon!

Comment: nice. thanks sir for your time. I wish I could accept your answer but not enough points

Comment: @KirollosShenouda - I should note that my book covers the new stuff in JavaScript in ES2015 onward, it's not a book about all of JavaScript. But since declarations in blocks is a new feature, it's covered (in Chapter 3). Block scope is also new, so it's covered (in Chapter 2). Happy coding!